# ¿Cómo hacer un ping pong en Windows Forms? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Cómo puedo crear una pelota funcional?

Dejo el código aquí:

```
public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    Graphics cuadrado = e.Graphics;
    Pen trazado = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
    Cuadrado(_X, _Y);
    Cuadrado2(_X, _Y);
    Pelota();



    void Cuadrado(int A, int B)
    {

        cuadrado.DrawLine(trazado, 80 + _X, 10 + _Y, 80 + _X, 100 + _Y);
        cuadrado.DrawLine(trazado, 81 + _X, 10 + _Y, 81 + _X, 100 + _Y);
        cuadrado.DrawLine(trazado, 82 + _X, 10 + _Y, 82 + _X, 100 + _Y);

    }

    void Cuadrado2(int A, int B)
    {

        cuadrado.DrawLine(trazado, 700 + _X2, 10 + _Y2, 700 + _X2, 100 + _Y2);
        cuadrado.DrawLine(trazado, 701 + _X2, 10 + _Y2, 701 + _X2, 100 + _Y2);
        cuadrado.DrawLine(trazado, 702 + _X2, 10 + _Y2, 702 + _X2, 100 + _Y2);

    }
```

Acá es donde creo las dos líneas, todavía no hice la pelota, porque no sé como generar su movimiento, solamente hice los controles que están aquí abajo de las barras.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //Player 1

    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.A))
    {
        _X -= 10;
        Refresh();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D))
    {
        _X += 10;
        Refresh();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.W))
    {
        _Y -= 10;

        Refresh();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.S))
    {
        _Y += 10;

        Refresh();
    }

    //Player 2

    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D4))
    {
        _X2 -= 10;
        Refresh();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D6))
    {
        _X2 += 10;
        Refresh();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D8))
    {
        _Y2 -= 10;

        Refresh();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D2))
    {
        _Y2 += 10;

        Refresh();
    }
```

¿Qué es recomendable para que la pelota funcione? Vi por ahí que muchos utilizan el *timer del Windows Form*, pero, ¿Cómo se lo implementaría a la pelota?

Comment: Hace un tiempo hice Asteroids en C#, con la capa de modelo y vista separadas y unidas por servicios, espero que mi ejemplo te ayude :
https://github.com/CesarSalazarSilva/JuegoAsteroids_ParadigmaOrientadoaServiciosyMVC
No me he tomado el tiempo de comentarlo al detalle, espero que el informe te ayude a entender y los comentarios que dejé en mi proyecto.

Comment: Puedo enviar el archivo en un .rar? porque basicamente no se como seguir el codigo, lo mio es para aprender

Comment: donde tienes la pelota? me imagino que en el método pelota() (coloca el codigo de pelota) tienes un random que desplace la pelota por la pantalla que definiste

Answer (score 0):

En mi respuesta no te voy a hacer el código pero espero solucione lo que pretendes o al menos ayude al enfoque.

Veo en tu código que los cuadrados tienen parámetros A y B que no son usados. Imagino que _X, _Y son globales pero entonces en los métodos para crear Cuadrado no son necesario A y B. Y en los movimientos usas Refresh() que son redundantes.

Bueno, yo definiría los cuadrados como rectángulos:

```
// Inicialmente en POS(10,10) situado a la izquierda
Rectangle Player1 = new Rectangle( 10,10,10,50);
// Inicialmente en POS(500,10) situado a la derecha
Rectangle Player1 = new Rectangle(500,10,10,50);
// La pelota
Rectangle Ball = new Rectangle(250,150,8,8);
```

Para la posición de los rectángulos y pelota usaría un tipo Point

```
Point PosPlayer1 = new Point(10,10);
Point PosPlayer2 = new Point(300,10);
Point PosBall = new Point(150, 150);
```

Los movimientos sería algo así:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //  Player 1

    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.A)) PosPlayer1.X -= 10;
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D)) PosPlayer1.X += 10;
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.W)) PosPlayer1.Y -= 10;
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.S)) PosPlayer1.Y += 10;

    //  Player 2

    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D4)) PosPlayer2.X -= 10;
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D6)) PosPlayer2.X += 10;
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D8)) PosPlayer2.Y -= 10;
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.D2)) PosPlayer2.Y += 10;

    // Habría que acotar para que no se fueran de la pantalla.
    if (PosPlayer1.Y < 0) PosPlayer1.Y = 0;
    if (PosPlayer2.Y < 0) PosPlayer2.Y = 0;  
    if (PosPlayer1.Bottom > 300) PosPlayer1.Y -= 10;
    if (PosPlayer2.Bottom > 300) PosPlayer2.Y -= 10;  

    // establecemos las nuevas posiciones de los cuadrados.
    Player1.Location = PosPlayer1;
    Player2.Location = PosPlayer2;

    // Redundante forzar redibujado aquí ya que en el timer que controlará el 
    // movimiento de la pelota hará un Refresh() cada 200 milisegundos 
    // Refresh();
}
```

Ya el metódo Paint quedaría de esta manera con la concepción que propongo:

```
public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen trazado = new Pen(Brushes.Red);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(trazado, Player1);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(trazado, Player2);

    DibujaPelota(e.Graphics);
}

public void DibujaPelota(Graphics g)
{
     Pen trazado = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
     
     g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, Ball); // Pelota Amarilla
     g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, Ball);     // Borde Negro
}
```

Ya sólo resta la inclusión de un control Timer en tu form y establecer sus propiedades según se desee. Yo probaría con Interval = 200 a ver cómo va. Evidentemente para el movimiento de la pelota precisamos una dirección para lo que también usaremos un objeto Point y un intervalo de desplazamiento.

```
// Inicialmente se mueve hacia la derecha y hacia abajo
Point BallDir = new Point(1,1);
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Velocity = 2; // Un valor de desplazamiento en pantalla

    PosBall.X += (Velocity * BallDir.X);
    PosBall.Y += (Velocity * BallDir.Y);
    
    // En este punto hay que comprobar si hay colisión con los cuadrados
    // o con los bordes del tablero; si colisiona actualiza la nueva
    // dirección que toma la pelota.
    CheckForCollision();
    
    // Establecemos la nueva posición de la pelota.
    Ball.Location = PosBall;


    // Forzamos dibujado
    Refresh();
    
    if ( EndOfTheGame() )
    {
        timer1.Stop(); // Detenemos el timer
        // Algun mensajito de quién ganó
        MessageBox.Show("Ganó... ");   
    }
}
```

Con este sistema que he propuesto es fácil implementar el método para comprobar si hay colisión. Ya que usaremos un Point para ver si choca con un cuadrado, los puntos claves son los puntos medios de los lados del rectángulo que contiene la pelota:

```
private void CheckForCollision()
{
   // Para comprobar si choca con Player1 uso el punto medio del lateral
   // izquierdo del rectángulo que contiene la pelota 
   if (Player1.Contains(new Point(Ball.Left, Ball.Top+4))
   {
       if (BallDir.X == -1) BallDir.X = 1;
   }
   // Para Player2 el opuesto
   if (Player2.Contains(new Point(Ball.Right, Ball.Top+4))
   {
       if (BallDir.X == 1) BallDir.X = -1;
   }
   // Para que se mantenga dentro del campo de juego comprobamos
   // si estamos dentro de los límites superior e inferior
   if (Ball.Y < 0 || Ball.Bottom > 300)
   {
      if (BallDir.Y == -1) BallDir.Y = 1; else BallDir.Y = -1;
   }          
}
```

Ya sólo quedaría implementar bool EndOfTheGame() que lo dejo ahí, si aún hay dudas o tienes dificultad no dudes en indicarlo.